# values_list on EmptyQuerySet used in a queryset filter returns full set

Tags: django, django-models

Recently found something peculiar in a filter, I can't believe its intended behaviour.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
print User.objects.filter(id__in=User.objects.none().values_list("id",flat=True))
print User.objects.filter(id__in=User.objects.all().values_list("id",flat=True))
```

Oddly both of these lists return the full set of users. It actually seems to be pretty easy to "fix" if I wrap the inner query in a list function e.g.

```
User.objects.filter(id__in=list(User.objects.none().values_list("id")))
```

Then this returns what I would expect (an empty list).

Seems like a bug to me, or am I missing something?

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the queries produced for both:

**User.objects.filter(id__in=User.objects.none().values_list("id",flat=True))**

```
SELECT "auth_user"."id",
       "auth_user"."username",
       "auth_user"."first_name",
       "auth_user"."last_name",
       "auth_user"."email",
       "auth_user"."password",
       "auth_user"."is_staff",
       "auth_user"."is_active",
       "auth_user"."is_superuser",
       "auth_user"."last_login",
       "auth_user"."date_joined"
FROM "auth_user"
WHERE "auth_user"."id" IN
    (SELECT U0."id"
     FROM "auth_user" U0) LIMIT 21
```

**User.objects.filter(id__in=User.objects.all().values_list("id",flat=True))**

```
SELECT "auth_user"."id",
       "auth_user"."username",
       "auth_user"."first_name",
       "auth_user"."last_name",
       "auth_user"."email",
       "auth_user"."password",
       "auth_user"."is_staff",
       "auth_user"."is_active",
       "auth_user"."is_superuser",
       "auth_user"."last_login",
       "auth_user"."date_joined"
FROM "auth_user"
WHERE "auth_user"."id" IN
    (SELECT U0."id"
     FROM "auth_user" U0) LIMIT 21
```

Notice anything? They're *exactly* the same queries. Also interesting is what happens if you try things like `User.objects.none()`, `User.objects.filter(id__in=[])` and `User.objects.filter(id__in=User.objects.none()`. In all three of these circumstances, Django short-circuits the query. In other words, it doesn't even issue a query to the database because it determines beforehand that there will not be any results. My best guess here is that adding `values_list` to the end defeats the short-circuiting logic, allowing an actual query to be send, and that it's actually `values_list` that determines the query that should be sent. Which in both cases is really the same, when you think about it. Either way you want to select just `id` on an *unfiltered* queryset.

I emphasized that part, because I'm sure you're jumping up and down now saying but `none` should return an empty queryset. True, but it does so by virtue of automatically returning an `EmptyQuerySet` and never actually querying the database at all. It doesn't add any filters to the query.

Whether this is a bug or not is debatable. I'm more apt to call this an edge-case that most likely can't really be "fixed". It's a function of how all the interweaving parts come together in this one scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the detail you went into. Interesting to know it doesn't actually hit the DB, though it makes perfect sense that it wouldn't. Do you think the problem could be solved by adding a 'def values_list(): return []' to the EmptyQuerySet class?

Comment: I don't think that in particular will work, but there might a way in general to override `values_list` such that it won't cause the query to be sent to the database. However, this is not really elegant: it would require subclassing `EmptyQuerySet`, `QuerySet` and `Manager` all just to get this to bubble-up and work properly, and since this is `User` you're working with, you'd have to monkey-patch `User` to add the custom manager. It's far more elegant to just adjust the code in place to account for this edge case, with an if statement checking if the queryset is empty before using it.

Comment: That sounds like much harder work than applying list(). Which works, im just waiting for someone to look at it in 6 months and undo it thinking im instance for running list on a list :). Thanks for the explanation.